# How to enable WDDM on NVIDIA P100?

Tags: windows, nvidia, tesla

We have machine with Windows Server 2019 and NVIDIA P100. When we install official driver we get TCC mode. For our application we need DirectX, but when we try to enable WDDM with `nvidia-smi` tool, we get error.

In documentation we found this:

> Tesla — typically defaults to TCC mode. Current drivers require a GRID license to enable WDDM on Tesla devices.

Does it mean we need GRID installed on our machine? We don't need VDI/vGPU, just WDDM enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion with NVIDIA support I finally got solution.

1. Create NVIDIA Enterprise Account.
2. Download "vGPU for Windows" package.
3. Install

After this steps you will have WDDM mode by default. Driver available in client's download section only allows TCC mode.